# Consequences of regretting Mitvas

Tags: shabbat

There is a concept that if one regrets doing a mitzva, it as if he had not done it.

If someone serves ice cream on Shabbos and I regret having eaten meat (which, according to some is a mitzva), is it like I never ate the meat (and am thus parve?)

meat on shabbos being a mitzva sourced within:
http://www.yutorah.org/_shiurim/Simchat%20Yom%20Tov.html

Comment: If you kill someone and regret killing them, do they come back to life?

Comment: What is your source for the concept asserted in the first sentence?

Comment: @Isaac Moses There are commentators that speak of this regarding the Akeidah and the death of Sara. If Avraham had regretted offering Yitzchak because Sarah died after hearing of it, he would have lost the merit of the offering.

Comment: @YEZ there is a physical component in that case. In this case,  only halachic components remain.

Comment: @ClintEastwood the meat leaves your stomach upon regret?

Comment: no, but is halachically nullified

Answer (score 5):

The point of the regret "cancelling" the mitzvah only deals with the reward of having performed a mitzvah. For example, if someone gives tzedakah and then "repents" of having given it. He can lose the "reward" of the mitzvah but he does not get the money back.

There is a medrash (from memory) of why Chayei Sarah is right after the akeidah. The medrash states that the satan arranged for Sarah to hear the news suddenly so that she suffered a heart attack and died. He wanted Avraham to regret having ever brought Yizchak to the akeidah, especially since he had not been sacrificed after all. Now that the news reached Sarah, and she died, perhaps he would regret being involved in the whole affair. if that had happened, while the events would have taken place, the spiritual reward would have been lost.

In the case of your question, you would not become pareve (physically) but you would not have the zechus of having carried out a mitzvah.